# GraphView рисует график только по первой точке

Tags: android, android-studio

имею проблему c библиотекой GraphView, прооблема заключается в том, что создается график только с 5 точками по **X** и дальше добавлять точки отказывается, как можно это исправить?

Мой класс реализации графика

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GraphView mGraph;
dbhelper dbhelper;
int [] marks;
int [] hours;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbhelper=new dbhelper(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
    mGraph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    ShowGraphics();


}
public void ShowGraphics(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int k=0;
    Cursor fine = database.query(dbhelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(fine.moveToFirst()){
        int ID = fine.getColumnIndex(dbhelper.KEY_ID);
        do{
            k=fine.getInt(ID);

        }while(fine.moveToNext());
    }
    fine.close();
    hours=new int[k];
    marks=new int[k];
    int i=0;
    Cursor cursor = database.query(dbhelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int time = cursor.getColumnIndex(dbhelper.KEY_TIME);
        int mark= cursor.getColumnIndex(dbhelper.KEY_MARK);
        do{

            String str="";
            str=cursor.getString(time);
            str=str.substring(1,3);

            marks[i]=cursor.getInt(mark);
            hours[i]=Integer.parseInt(str);
            i=i+1;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {

    });
    i=0;
    for(int j=0; j<k;j++) {
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(i+5, marks[i]), true, 40);
        i++;
    }

    mGraph.addSeries(series);

}
```

}

Comment: Весьма смутно выразился, у меня есть деление дня по часам, и после 13 часов, постройка графика заканчивается на 8 и затем бесконечность

Answer (score 0):

В документации по этой библиотеке на сайте[Документация по библиотеке](http://www.android-graphview.org/static-labels/), вполне понятно как это всё сделать, присутствуют команды с их описанием. Пора научится сначала читать инструкции а потом уж задавать глупые вопросы